# What is this weird mechanical thing I found in the woods?

Tags: animals, hunting

I hope this is the right community.
I was walking through the woods and found this weird thing, it was in front of a hunting tower, and a wildlife cam was pointed at it.

There where traces of deer(?) around it.

It's basically a big metal crank that is mounted to a metal stick and something seems to drag it in circles.
Does anybody know what this might be?

[image]

(click to enlarge image)

This picture was taken close to Vienna Austria in the Danube meadows/wetlands.

Comment: Where in the world are you? I suspect it's some form of bait device but without knowing what the local wildlife might be, it's hard to know for sure, or what for (guess: wild boar)

Comment: close to vienna austria in the danube meadows/wetlands

Comment: So the circular track is an imprint from the cylinder's outer rim as it rolls around at the limit of the tether ??

Comment: @Criggie the proportions look right for that, don't they?

Comment: Looks like a hidden Goa'uld ring device, with a Naquadah reactor ready for transport.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fact that's it's staked out near a hunting tower suggests it's bait to attract animals.  A couple of factors suggest it's meant for wild boar (which are found in Austria), or at least to withstand them:

- It's clearly tough, and so are boar. A heavy (recycled machinery?) bait holder will keep them still or slowly moving for a good shot.
- Hunting towers are used for boar, not far away in Germany (they give a good view, and the shot is downwards meaning that a miss hits the ground).  Bait is sometimes used with them.
- Omnivorous, curious boar are more likely to be attracted to bait in a device like that than other species that are legally hunted (deer), and will spend time trying to get the bait out, or drag the whole thing away.

You mention deer-like tracks.  [Wild boar tracks](https://www.mammal.org.uk/species-hub/full-species-hub/discover-mammals/species-wild-boar/) are similar to large deer tracks, but the dew claws are particularly obvious and widely spaced [as seen in this image](https://www.mdwfp.com/media/4463/wild-hog-tracks_openroadoutdoors.jpg) (not embedded due to unclear licensing).

Comment: thank you for the explanation, wild boar are pretty common in and arround viennas woods so it makes totatlly sense thank you

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, but I'm not guaranteed to be right, so it might be worth seeing if anyone disagrees with me

Comment: a friend of mine knows a hunter and he said he thinks its whats called a "kirrung" in german,
it's basically a tube filled with corn or something similar, the boar then rolls it in a circle and corn will drop out

Comment: Yeah we use very similar methods over a different Austrian border (Czech Republic), usually made of high durability plastic and tethered with a serious chain to a tree. The plastic has holes roughly 1cm in diameter and is filled with corn/pea/grain mixtures. Usually eaten mostly by boar that toss the cylinders around until all the feed spills out. Seeing deer tracks around one of these wouldn't be anything special where I hunt, since we don't specifically bait boar. There is often other bait in the same place for deer (fallow/roe).

Comment: Yes it's for wild pig. We colloquially call the toy Sauenkreisel (sow roundabout) and the area with such toys a Schweinespielplatz (pig playground). Kirrung is more generally any place wherer small amounts of feed are put as bait for wild animals.

Comment: "Kirrung" (noun) roughly translates to "bait site". eg: [Auf Linie bringen – richtig kirren](https://wildundhund.de/auf-linie-bringen-richtig-kirren/) ("to coo properly")... the actual purpose is not only to make them halt, but to be able to conveniently fire at the broadside, which results in a better hit/miss ratio; that tube/can is called a "Kirrtrommel".

Comment: The search term [Kirrtrommel](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kirrtrommel) turns up matching pictures; it's usually filled with maize. There's also regulations for that; eg. [Regelungen.pdf](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/images/b/b1/Regelungen.pdf) (similar might exist in Austria).